# "DELETE_TODO" in a basic todo project

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I'm a very beginner in redux I created a basic todo app but I can't figure it out how to make delete reducers. That's what I tried, what do I need to change and how do I dispatch it in my Todolist.js file.

Reducers.js

```js
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false,
        },
      ];
    case "DELETE_TODO":
      return state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default todos;
```

TodoList.js(Here there when I click the button I want to delete it).

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteTodo } from "../actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state,
  };
};

const TodoList = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {state.todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.text}
            <button>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

actions.js

```js
let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addTodo = (text) => ({
  type: "ADD_TODO",
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text,
});

export const deleteTodo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    id: id,
  };
};
```

I know its very basic but I need help for it.

Comment: Can you update what happens with this code? Can you add todo successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The reducer looks fine to me, `return state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.id);` will correctly filter and return a new array object with all todo's with a non-matching `id` property.

## Dispatch action to delete todo

The delete todos action needs to be wired up to your UI. *Assumes your code can correctly add todos already.*

Given action creator

```
const deleteTodo = (id) => ({
  type: "DELETE_TODO",
  id: id,
});
```

You just need to map dispatch to props for the action creator and connect

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  deleteTodo,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

You'll now have a `deleteTodo` callback wrapped in a call to dispatch to use within the component.

*Reminder, react components are passed `props`, not "state"*.

```
const TodoList = ({ deleteTodo, todos }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.text}
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} // <-- call action and pass id
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, you should have Actions i.e 'DELETE_TODO' and a Dispatcher to dispatch your actions to your Store thru a Reducer to generate or modify State so your components can Select from store. However, here what you can add to your code hopefully make it work.
actions.js

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';
export const DELETE_TODO = 'DELETE_TODO';

export const addTodo = (todo) => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: todo,
});

export const deleteTodo = (id) => ({
  type: DELETE_TODO,
  payload: id,
});
```

in reducers.js

```
import { ADD_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from './actions';
const initialState = { todos: [], };
const TodoList = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
      };
    case DELETE_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default TodoList;
```

and now in your TodoList.js component you need to select the state from the store
and make your dispatchers
TodoList.js

```
import React,{useCallback} from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
// import addTodo and deleteTodo from where you put store i.e:
// import { addTodo, deleteTodo } from '../store/todos/actions'
// import todoList from '../store/todos/reducers


// from here goes inside your component

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const onDeleteTodo = useCallback(id) => dispatch(deleteTodo(id)), [dispatch],);
const onAddTodo = useCallback(todo) => dispatch(addTodo(todo)),[dispatch],);
```